# Linux globbing - exclude files that contain a hyphen/dash in filename

Tags: linux, shell, glob

I want to ignore all files that contain a dash/hyphen in filename.

```
$ ls /home/user/logs/*.log
access.log
error.log
access-2020-05-27.log
access-2020-05-26.log
error-2020-05-27.log
error-2020-05-26.log
```

I only want it to list access.log and error.log

I tried this but it does the exact opposite of what I want. Lists all files with a dash/hyphen

```
ls /home/user/logs/*[-]*.log
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two work OK with bash:

```
ls *[A-Za-z].log

ls *[^0-9].log
```

Also:

```
ls | grep -v -e -
```